# Beginner tutorial for Sitecore8 developer

Tags: sitecore

I come from an ASP.Net (no mvc knowledge) background and would like to learn Sitecore 8 development.

Looking for basic step-by-step tutorials to build a site. But its hard finding them online. Some are for lower versions and the official site has articles on individual topics.

Kindly point me to any such articles that will help me learn the basics of building a Site for Sitecore8.

Thank you.

**UPDATE**
Here is a tutorial I've written, which will help beginners learn Sitecore development, by building a sample website:

https://saltandsitecore.wordpress.com/2017/04/01/building-a-sitecore-website-with-mvc-part-1/

Comment: This type of question isn't appropriate for SO. I suggest you post it at https://community.sitecore.net/, where I'm sure there'll be many ready to help and discuss.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is plenty of information regarding Sitecore in the internet for a quick start. I would recommend just few of them:

http://learnsitecore.cmsuniverse.net/

https://www.cmssource.co.uk/blog/2012/June/basic-sitecore-development-tutorial-part-1-introduction
https://sitecorebasics.wordpress.com/2011/05/13/basics-of-sitecore-for-beginner-developers/

You will need to understand how to create pages, how **data templates** work and presentation details like **layouts** and **renderings** and other fundamentals

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore%20experience%20platform/creating%20and%20editing%20items
https://www.cmssource.co.uk/blog/2012/June/basic-sitecore-development-tutorial-part-6-layout-and-sublayout-implementation

You will also need to find out some architecture basics about Sitecore, like content management and delivery servers and **databases** used for that (core, master, web). What is **publishing** and how it works, and why is it important.

http://learnsitecore.cmsuniverse.net/en/Editors/Articles/2009/07/PublishingAndVersioning.aspx

Also it would be very benefocious to understand **Experience Editor** (previously called Page Editor) and what are the particularities of creating pages to support it; as well as the advantages it brings to business users.

https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/70/page_editor_recommended_practices_for_developers_70-a4.pdf

There are also some differences in **MVC** approach you need to understand before doing Sitecore with MVC. You need to understand View Renderings and Controller Renderings, as well as how the routing works in Sitecore MVC.

http://sitecore.unic.com/2015/06/24/the-sitecore-mvc-puzzle/
http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2015/02/how-is-sitecore-mvc-different-from-aspnet-mvc.aspx
http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/business-blogs/technical-trends/posts/2012/06/mvc-and-sitecore-651-overview.aspx

There are other aspects of Sitecore you may need to understand: **workflows**, **caching**, **indexing**, **pipelines**, **events**, sitecore **security model** etc. Generally, speaking, the question you asked is to wide even to answer that by sharing the links. But those I quoted is enough to start

There are many YouTube channels that may be much more helpful for the beginner:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yytEQnJpF1I

https://www.youtube.com/user/mastersitecore

https://www.youtube.com/user/sitecoreceptraining

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AQGtFA8Ud2Q&list=PL5QMcxdLbK7gGSTcPZJal2i5GHu1VHrl4

Also, if you budget allow that, you may consider to take official training courses - they are quite helpful for the beginners. 
http://www.sitecore.net/services-and-support/training.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The basics of building a Sitecore site are very similar from earlier versions of Sitecore.  If you haven't been on the Sitecore training, I recommend doing that as it will teach you the main basics.

These are some good basic tutorials http://learnsitecore.cmsuniverse.net/en/GlobalNavigation/Sitecore-beginners-guide.aspx - although they are older, they are still valid.

Also the docs at https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore%20experience%20platform can help you with Sitecore 8 details.